# Cannot create Euro Symbol

Tags: text-object

I am working with text (standard Blender font) on a Mac. No problem with the currency symbols for yen, dollar, pound but somehow I cannot create the euro symbol. It should be <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> on a mac. Blender displays the euro symbol in the Tool Shelf (*Edit Mode*), but when I toggle into *Object Mode* the glyph won't show up.

Comment: This could be considered a bug, or rather a missing feature in the BFont font. You would not be wrong to submit this as a bug report to the issue tracker. It's an established currency...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blender's default font for *Text* Objects (called "BFont") doesn't have the Euro symbol (August 2015). Import a different font, one that does have the Euro `€` symbol.

```
obj = bpy.data.objects['some_text_object']
obj.data.body = chr(8364) * 4
```

This would show 4 Euro symbols, if the Glyph is present in the table.

Comment: Hope you don't mind asking, but what font is close to BFont ? I like the "industrial" look

Comment: it's very similar to `Johnston` typeface https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnston_(typeface).

Comment: @JanScherders You could also try [Gill Sans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gill_Sans).

Comment: yes, Gill Sans is available as Mac font and I think I would have to buy the Johnston fonts

Comment: Gill Sans indeed comes closer